# Debugging React propType warnings

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have propType expressions that sometimes are emitting warnings.

When that happens, I would like to inspect the object causing the warning since the warning message in the console is in same cases not helpful enough.

I tried to debugging through the spec code of react to find the right spot for the breakpoint, however i would expect there is an easier way to get more diagnostic information about the warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Want the ugly solution? Because that's all I have.

Stick this in your main application file.

```
const error = console.error;
console.error = (...args) => {
    debugger;
    error.apply(null, args);
}
```

And use the debugger to walk up the callchain till you find `checkReactTypeSpec` and look at its arguments.

Comment: yeah. that's roughly what i am doing now. i was hoping for a better approach :(

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/84084153edbeab515f9955b4c5b955ef95167787/src/renderers/dom/client/wrappers/LinkedValueUtils.js#L105) I don't see any. They're logging via [warning](https://www.npmjs.com/package/warning) which doesn't seem to offer any hooks either.